# Proving a lower Bound on Chromatic Number $\chi (G) > 2k$ contains a $k-$connected Subgraph

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, coloring, graph-connectivity

Show that if $\chi (G) >2k$ then $G$ contains a $k-$connected subgraph.

In graphs of large chromatic number, I studied a recent paper on the extension on the fact: "that every graph of chromatic number at least $4k + 1$ contains a subgraph of connectivity at least $k$ " result by [W. Mader]. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.00533.pdf But I am stuck on this problem.
Any hint or help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  It seems that recent papers in this area reference Mader’s result (which is originally about average degree rather than chromatic number).  If a stronger bound like this were known I would expect it to have been cited.

Comment: I think you're right @ErickWong The problem is  part of my home work questions.

Comment: @ErickWong I have added a link to a recent paper on such bounds.

Comment: Could you please outline a proof of this problem? If this is part of your homework questions then I would expect you have known the proof by now.